# Most flexible UI Framework for Windows endpoint?

Tags: windows, requirements

I am tasked with designing and implementing a flexible UI solution for deployment across a series of "kiosk"-ed Windows endpoints. There is some debate about what is the considered to be the best technology solution for the actual UI itself. The requirements are:

- Must be hardware accelerated
- Must play WMV video (for licensing reasons)
- Must be skinnable/themeable.
- Must support off-screen rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF handles all of those.

It is fully HW accelerated. It plays WMV through [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) class. It was designed with themability from the begining, not unlike many bolt-on solutions found in WinForms libraries. And it allows rendering of visuals into a bitmap through [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx), which I assume you mean by "off-screen rendering".